# Can't access SerialPort on virtual machine

Tags: windows-8.1, vmware-workstation, serial-port

I'm using VMware Workstation 10.0.4 with a Windows 8.1 64bit as OS on the virtual machine (and the host system). Now I am facing the problem that though the serial port is mapped into the virtual machine, it doesn't work anymore after a while and I have no clue why.

When I copy the "fresh" machine to my hdd and execute it for the first time, everything works. But after installing some things or changing os specific settings or sometimes taking a snapshot the port cannot be accessed anymore by putty. It tells me that it is unable to open the serial port but VMware shows that the port is still connected with the virtual machine. If I disconnect the port and try it on the host computer, everything works.

What did I try so far:

- Reboot virtual machine
- Reboot host system
- SerialPort disconnected and reconnected in the virtual machine
- Reset the VM, same problem after a while

Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The VMware virtual BIOS can address two serial ports by default, and similar technique can be used to enable the extra parallel ports, however this article link below concentrates on the serial ports only. I got this from VMWare Knowledge center...Did you try this steps already? Hope this was helpful (link below)

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1002463

Comment: I saw that article but I'm not sure how this will solve my problem? I have one serial port on the device which is accessible via `COM1` on the host os and mapped as `COM1` into the virtual machine. Why do I need COM3 and COM4?

Answer (score 0):

The program I am working on is starting a service that blocks the serial port and my colleagues forgot to mention that...No problems with VMware or anything else